# LPTHW - Second bracket '[' to create dictionary not working, even though Zed Shaw is using it

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm going through Zed Shaw's Learn Python The Hard Way textbook (LPTHW).

When Zed creates dictionaries he is using second bracket to create them. Such as:

```
# Creating an empty dictionary
dict = []
```

Here is a picture example where he used a dictionary to create a setup file for a project, using second brackets to create a dictionary called 'config':

[link : implementation of dictionary from his workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5bm9.png)

But this is giving me an error. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. For some weird reason, Zed uses second brackets to create dictionaries BUT you should be using curly brackets. Hope this helps everyone else!

```
# Creating an empty dictionary
config = {}
```

Comment: don't use `dict`. Since the other alternative is `d = dict()`

Comment: and I think you misread the book. those `[]` are creating an empty `list`

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about dictionaries. Please check the link with the image I have attached to the question. Thanks !

Comment: yeah, the book is very wrong !! Maybe the author wants you to learn python the hard way by feeding you bulls**t :)